# swipeDown doesn't work in Uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I am trying to use Android UIautomator and trying to swipeDown() a view to open another view. But I have failed to do so. I have tried swipeLeft() and swipeRight() for other layouts and I succeeded, but can't find a solution why this is not happening for swipeDown().

the code I have wrote so far:

```
UiObject drawer=new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android:id/tabs"));
    drawer.swipeDown(5);
```

I have read all the possible documents and can't find what I am doing wrong. Please let me know what I have done wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure that the UiObject *drawer* in your case is visible, if it is not visible swipeDown can not be performed.

try something like this, then you can see what fails!

```
if (drawer.waitForExists(1000))
{
   boolean swipeWasPerformed = drawer.swipeDown(5);
   Log.i(swipeWasPerformed);

}
```